# Ranking Elevation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation

Can QGIS automatically find the lowest land-point in a country and when you would like to, find the second lowest, third lowest land-point and so on? And on that same coin, a software that could find the highest point, second highest, third highest point etc?

Checked out QGIS and did the tutorial, but it seems to be a program where you build maps.

Comment: QGIS will do what you need, look into the Zonal Statistics plugin.

Comment: Hi Dan C, Thanks for your response. I will look into that. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi again Dan, it seems it's already installed. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating maps is component of QGIS, but it is not the primary purpose of that or any other GIS program. Analysis is, including answering the kind of question you have (where are the lowest/highest points). You mention you did 'the tutorial' but not which one. There are a few specifically dedicated to working with terrain and elevation, for example:

- http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/rasters/terrain_analysis.html
- http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/terrain%20analysis/

The first thing you'll need to know is you have to acquire the data to work with, typically a DEM. Those come in varying resolutions. Elevation is a continuous type of data, with an infinite number of values depending on how closely you sample, so when represented as data you pick a resolution or sample rate. A common source, SRTM, is typically 30m resolution (for some parts of the world, 90m for others). That means you get one elevation reading for every 30 square meters. Obviously in mountainous areas this won't always adequately represent the terrain. But there's a trade-off because higher resolution means larger files and more data. At a *country* level, depending on the country, you probably wouldn't want to work with a 1m resolution file. Even at a *county* level here in the US, 10m is 'pretty detailed'.

Once you've acquired the data and figured out how to query/symbolize/work with it, you can refine your question. Single lowest point? Lowest point with at least 20m gain and fall again between it and the next low area? You'll need to come up with criteria that defines one 'point' from another (this is common with mountains and determining if a point is a separate peak or mountain or just a sub-peak or something). And you'll understand how the actual point location you determine is an approximation or area, not necessarily *the* point. The data will show you the range of values, and you'll have to examine where those values fall in terms of pixel location and how connected they are. The tutorials above cover how to do this, including creating new rasters or symbolizing only those pixels above or below a threshold - so you look at the data range, determine the lowest value, add say 10 to that, and then look at only the locations of pixels below that threshold.

Comment: Hi Chris W. Thanks for your elaborate response. I did the tutorial Module 1-5 where you learn to add layers like roads, urban area and farm area. I just recently got into cartography and GIS more seriously, so i'm still pretty   beginner when it comes to it :) 

Would downloading a shapefile help ? The country i'm interested in is Lesotho.

Comment: @Anders Adding layers and such is some of the basic stuff, because you have to add it to work with it (*do* analysis). Further in to the tutorials you start to get into simple analysis operations, which you can then string together into more complex solutions. Elevation data is typically in a raster format, like a DEM. Shapefiles are vector. You *can* get elevation data in vector as points or lines, but as I said it's continuous data so it's usually done as a raster. That country is fairly small, so a 10m file if you can find one might be manageable. But I don't know of a source.

Comment: Thanks Chris W ! Show your Manager this message, Give Chris W a raise, he's been very helpful, proffessional and quick ! Thanks again. Will try to do the whole course and try to learn this software. Have a great day !

Comment: @Anders Happy to help. Note this is a volunteer site; people providing answers and comments are just like you. You might want to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an idea how the site works. If you feel my answer has fully addressed your question, you might consider clicking the check mark to accept the answer - with a bit more rep you'll be able to upvote questions and answers you find useful. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more info.

Comment: Nice answer! I hereby bequeath upon you a 200% raise on your current rate of no salary. Don't spend it all in one place!